# How to extract nested value from api reponse in ansible

Tags: api, debugging, ansible, citrix, msg

I am writing a simple ansible (v2.5) playbook, that makes a call to the NITRO API on a Citrix netscaler and gets a 200 response like this back (per device in inventory that this is ran against):

```
{ "errorcode": 0, "message": "Done", "severity": "NONE", "vrid": [ { "id": "32", "state": "1", "ifaces": "LA\/2 " }, { "id": "65", "state": "0" }, { "id": "80", "state": "1", "ifaces": "LA\/1 " } ] }
```

I am registering this response in a variable named "citrix_result" in my playbook.

I am trying to use debug msg's to output a report in some human-friendly format, preferrably csv for easy copy/paste into excel.

What I really need is to loop over each instance of "id" in the citrix_results 200-responses to produce something like this (hostname would be repeated in case of multiple vrid's like in the above reponse):

```
...
inventory_hostname1,id1 value,state1 value,ifaces1 value
inventory_hostname1,id2 value,state2 value
inventory_hostname1,id3 value,state3 value,ifaces3 value
...
```

This would be simple, if I were pulling this response into Python lists and dicts.  But unfortunately, I work in a strictly Ansible shop and need to do this via ansible (which I am obviously kinda new at).

Also, this ansible playbook is being run via Jenkins automation from a GitHub repo, so I cannot really wrap this playbook within a python script to further manipulate or postprocess the 200 response afterwards.  It needs to be vanilla ansible/jinja2 and in simple format that can be easily copied from ansible execution output.

Here is the complete playbook, as of today (including some of below solution):

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    attributes:
      id: id
      state: state
      ifaces: ifaces
  tasks:

  - name: query_vrID_via_nitro_api
    delegate_to: localhost
    ignore_errors: true
    uri:
      url: "http://{{ nsip }}/nitro/v1/config/vrid?attrs={{ attributes.id }},{{ attributes.state }},{{ attributes.ifaces }}"
      method: GET
      status_code: 200
      return_content: yes
      headers:
        X-NITRO-USER: "{{ nitro_user }}"
        X-NITRO-PASS: "{{ nitro_pass }}"
    register: citrix_result

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - shell: cat 'api.json'
      register: result

    - debug: var=result

    - set_fact: myvar="{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: create_output_file
      template:
        src: results.j2
        dest: ./files/report.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: create_output_file
      template:
        src: results.j2
        dest: ./files/report.csv
```

jinja Template:

```
inventory_hostname,id,state,ifaces
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{% set output=hostvars[host]['citrix_result']['stdout'] | from_json %}
{% for item in output['vrid'] %}

{{ host }},{{ item.id }},{{ item.state }}{% if item.ifaces is defined %},{{ item.ifaces }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Report:

```
inventory_hostname,id,state,ifaces

52.90.34.153,32,1,LA/2 
52.90.34.153,65,0
52.90.34.153,80,1,LA/1 
34.230.61.32,32,1,LA/2 
34.230.61.32,65,0
34.230.61.32,80,1,LA/1
```

Comment: Thanks, Sudhar!! I will give this a try.

Comment: I added my complete playbook.  How do I get my "citrix_result" variable value into the "api.json" call?  Is the "api.json" just a placeholder you used to represent the json response?